# Django: automatically choose model based on parameters entered in as another models values

Tags: python, django, database-design, django-apps

I am creating a Django file browser app where it crawls files and makes the metadata available to view and search.

After initially entering the file as a "file" object, I would like to create a "video", "music", or "document"  based on the extension of the file.

Some mock models...

```
class File(models.Model):
    createdate = models.DateTimeField('date file entered', db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
    cdate = models.DateTimeField()
    hash = models.CharField(max_length=14, default=_make_hash, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
    filename = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=2048)
    fullpath = models.CharField(max_length=2048)
    folder = models.CharField(max_length=2048)


class Video(models.Model):
    createdate = models.DateTimeField('date file entered', db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
    imdblink = models.CharField(max_length=2048)
    container = models.CharField(max_length=2048)


class Music(models.Model):
    createdate = models.DateTimeField('date file entered', db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
    bitrate = models.CharField(max_length=2048)
    artistname = models.CharField(max_length=2048)
    songname = models.CharField(max_length=2048)


class FileType(models.Model):
    typename = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    extension = models.ForeignKey(FileExtension)


class FileExtension(models.Model):
    extension = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

1. A FileType of Video would be created with "avi,mpg,mp4,mkv", Music with "mp3,flac" and so on.
2. The Django app would be run over Video1.avi, Video2.mpg, Song1.mp3, Song2.flac etc. They would be entered into the database as a File object.
3. On save of the File object, the app would look at the files extension, compare it to the list and choose an appropriate model laid out by the FileType model.

I am hoping to keep the model choice parameters as database entries so I can add or remove without having to change the app.

I am unsure of how to reference which model I want the FileType entry to be.

Any advice or input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to do what you are trying to do, I would have the `FileType` model include another `CharField` named `file_type_model_class`. It would contain the name of the model class, such as `Music`. You can instantiate your class using something like this:

```
ft = FileType.objects.get(pk = some_id)
module = __import__('ff.models')
class_ = getattr('ff.models', ft.file_type_model_class)
instance = class_()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to relate your file instance to one of video or music, you might want to try [Generic Foreign Key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#id1)

```
class File(models.Model):
    # Your other fields...
    file_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
        limit_choices_to={"model__in": ("video", "music")},
        help_text=_("Is this video or music?"))
    file_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        help_text=_("Which specific video or music (by ID)?"))
    file_object = generic.GenericForeignKey(ct_field="file_type",
       fk_field="file_id")

    def save():
        # Do your work here on self.filename to determine self.file_type
```